# Should I let administrator account bypass IP ACL?

Tags: account-security, ip, account-lockout

Let's say there is a system that can set IP ACL for security.
If administrator can't bypass IP ACL, account may by locked up when machine or network IP changed
But if administrator can bypass IP ACL, then an attacker can bypass IP ACL when got administrator account. IP ACL gets meaningless.

Is there good way to mitigate both situations?

Comment: If your administrator account is compromised, you've got bigger problems and many other protections are rendered "meaningless".

Comment: When IP ACL enabled, attacker should hack physical device in IP ACL range, even if administrator account has been compromised. But this leads to losing control of IP is losing account.